# Excel - El resultado de la formula en la casilla es diferente al que me sale ejecutando F9

Tags: excel

Veran mi problema en excel es el siguiente: se encuestaron a cierta cantidad de alumnos y cada uno escribio el id de curso que lleva con el id de profesor, la cuestion es contar los cursos por profesor sin repetirse, ya que muchos alumnos encuestados llevan la misma clase con el mismo profe.

La formula que yo hice si me da el resultado que quiero, pero solo me muestra el valor cuando lo selecciono y apreto F9, por que en la casilla solo me muestra el valor 0. Y no se por que sucede eso.

[LINK AL EXCEL CON LOS DATOS]
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TT2w8XnbTBvERPmRn6wGHx4xbM20kax-/view?usp=sharing

Agradeceria su ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ser más específico, para contar la cantidad de cursos por profesor, deberías usar la función "contar.si" donde en rango seleccionas todos los cursos y en criterio seleccionas el id del profesor.
En una tabla tienes el código de los alumnos, cursos y profes y en otra tabla tienes el id de profesores y al costado puedes poner cantidad de cursos y esa función funciona muy bien para eso.

Comment: Si funcionaria el "contar si", pero me contaría todos los cursos de la tabla, incluyendo los que se repiten o no? ..por que como digo la encuesta fue a los alumnos y pues dos alumnos llevan el mismo curso con el mismo profesor y entonces el "contar si" lo contaria como dos cuando en realidad es un curso. o ¿si cuenta como uno esas dos encuestas repetidas?

Answer (score 0):

Para ayudarte en tu problema, agregas dos columnas al lado de id profe, en la columna H en el encabezado le puedes poner CURSOS NO REPETIDOS (H2) y en la celda H3 escribes la siguiente fórmula "**=SI.ERROR(INDICE($F$3:$F$765, COINCIDIR(0, INDICE(CONTAR.SI($H$2:H2, $F$3:$F$765), 0, 0), 0)), "")**" en la columna I puedes poner de encabezado CURSOS X PROFE (I2) luego en la celda I3 escribes la siguiente fórmula "**=SI.ERROR(INDICE($E$3:$H$765,COINCIDIR(H3,$F$3:$F$765,0),3),"")**" en la columna K te quedaría tu LISTADO DE PROFES, al costado en el encabezado le puedes poner CANT. DE CURSOS (L2), en la celda L3 escribes la siguiente fórmula "**=CONTAR.SI($I$3:$I765,K3)**"

Con eso quedaría resuelto tu problema ;)